# How to copy specific value from one column to another in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[54789, 'John', 24], [np.nan, 62549, 28], [3547, 'Maggie', 31], [np.nan, 1345, 21], [np.nan, "Luke", 22]]), columns=['ID', 'Name', 'Age'])
df
      ID    Name Age
0  54789    John  24
1    nan   62549  28
2   3547  Maggie  31
3    nan    1345  21
4    nan    Luke  22
```

I need to grab all those numbers wrongly placed in the "Name" column and copy them to the ID column. Resulting DataFrame should look like this:

```
      ID    Name Age
0  54789    John  24
1  62549   62549  28
2   3547  Maggie  31
3   1345    1345  21
4    nan    Luke  22
```

I tried a number of ways to copy values in a column to another column:

```
df["ID"] = [row[2] if row[2].isdigit else row[1] for row in df.itertuples()]
df.loc[df["ID"]=="nan"] = df.loc[df['Name'].str.isdigit(),"Name"]
```

Nothing worked so far, I either bring in the name Luke (which should not come) or I only bring the first number...Any solutions?

Comment: Defining `df` in this way, you will get all elements as strings, even for numeric values and np.nan.   54789 (number) becomes '54789' (string).  np.nan becomes 'nan' (string).  Do you mean it ?   Don't use np.array if you want to keep the element types.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I did not mean to do that, the actual DataFrame I'm working on came from a csv file, this was just supposed to be an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pandas.Series.str.isnumeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) with `np.where`

```
df['ID'] = np.where(df.Name.str.isnumeric(), df.Name, df.ID)
```

Output

```
      ID    Name Age
0  54789    John  24
1  62549   62549  28
2   3547  Maggie  31
3   1345    1345  21
4    nan    Luke  22
```